# Why is my second div hiding behind the opening div?

Tags: html, css

I'm going for a minimalist design that opens with a full page introduction. This introduction sits in the `.front-page` div that covers 100% of the available screen.

Then there's another div that is supposed to go beneath the `.front-page` when you scroll down, but for some reason it sits at `position 0` at the top of the screen, completely hidden behind the `.front-page` div.

I know if I wanted to I could just position it manually but that's bad coding practice. There has to be a simple solution that I'm overlooking.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  font-family: "Architects Daughter", cursive;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50%;
}

.arrow {
  font-size: 2em;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.front-page {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 7;
  display: block;
}

.social-bar {
  height: auto;
}

.social-bar a {
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

.scrolling {
  display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 701px) {
  .arrow {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Head -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bfd52c390d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div class="front-page">
  <div class="intro">
    <header>
      <h1>Guinevere <br> E. <br> Mayberry</h1>
      <h4>Front-End Web Development &mdash; Largo, Florida</h4>
    </header>

    <!-- Load external JavaScript -->
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>

    <div class="social-bar">
      <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="pillowfort"><i class="fas fa-blog"></i></a>
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="scrolling">
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your front page has position absolute - is there a reason you have this?

Comment: `position: absolute;` positions the element to the closest relative parent element. In this case you have no relative element defined and as such the body is used. So the the element will always cover the entire body. Why not simply give the element a heigt of: `height: 100vh;` instead of moving it out of flow?

Comment: @tacoshy originally that was what I did, but that still left a problem of a white strip about 5px wide around the top, left, and right of the div

Comment: thats the default body margin which for most browsers is 8px. PS: `height:100%` only works if you have a defined height not a calculated one `for nearly all your elements it has no effect.

Comment: @tacoshy that fixed it lol. I knew there was something simple I was overlooking, it was the default body margin that had me all screwed up, that and absolute positioning. If you put that as an answer I'll mark this as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cut your code down and removed all unecessary CSS lines.
I simply added `body { margin: 0; }` to reset the default body margin.
Then I just added `front-page { height: 100vh; }` to let it cover the entire viewports height.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  font-family: "Architects Daughter", cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

.arrow {
  font-size: 2em;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.front-page {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  height: 100vh;
}

.social-bar a {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 701px) {
  .arrow {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Head -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bfd52c390d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div class="front-page">
  <div class="intro">
    <header>
      <h1>Guinevere <br> E. <br> Mayberry</h1>
      <h4>Front-End Web Development &mdash; Largo, Florida</h4>
    </header>

    <!-- Load external JavaScript -->
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>

    <div class="social-bar">
      <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="pillowfort"><i class="fas fa-blog"></i></a>
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="scrolling">
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy approach will be removing `position` and use `position: relative` instead of `absolute` so that other `div` spanning area is respected and if you want full screen `.front-page` use height: 100vh;`else using`height: 100%`will be up to content area only (**also`width: 100%``` will cover whole screen width**) .

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  font-family: "Architects Daughter", cursive;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50%;
}

.arrow {
  font-size: 2em;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.front-page {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
   width: 100vw;/* no need here, covers full screen width*/
  height: 100vh;
  /*so that covers full screen height*/
  /*position: relative; use when you need to use top/bottom... property*/
  z-index: 7;
  display: block;
}

.social-bar {
  height: auto;
}

.social-bar a {
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 701px) {
  .arrow {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Head -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bfd52c390d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div class="front-page">
  <div class="intro">
    <header>
      <h1>Guinevere <br> E. <br> Mayberry</h1>
      <h4>Front-End Web Development &mdash; Largo, Florida</h4>
    </header>

    <!-- Load external JavaScript -->
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>

    <div class="social-bar">
      <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="pillowfort"><i class="fas fa-blog"></i></a>
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="scrolling">
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
  <p>text to allow scrolling</p>
</div>
```

Comment: why use `position: relative`? i has no use in this case and can be leftout. Yous till overflowing because of margins and box-sizing and paddings. no reason to remain display: block as it is the default setting of a div. Height 100% has no influence at all since none of the elemnts is defined, they are all calculated so the default `height: auto` will remain active.

Comment: I told `position: relative` if needed to reposition can use `top/bottom` property without overlaying on other divs and `*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}` must be added so that padding are inside width of container and default `margin/ paddings` can be removed

Comment: *using position: relative instead of absolute* -> `position: relative` is not a part of a solution. Position relative was never intended here. Also it has no effect if you have no absoltue positioned child element. As you dont have that case, you should have removed it instead of changing it. No reason to define `width: 100vw;` which will cause the overflow. The default `width: auto;` will exactly fit the parents. This makes a margin and paddign reset unecssary. Beside of that you should not global reset margin and paddings. It causes more issues then it does good.

Comment: why is `*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}` not advised as it helped me a lot in my codes

Comment: because it is like a nuke. It nukes everything and then you have to re-add the margins and paddings for most elements manually. easier to just remove the margin of the body and not being required to fix the paddings and margins of the other elements manually. text that is positioned directly at the screens edge because of missing margin/paddings are harder to read.

Comment: I will remember that and is `body` tag also has some `margin`

Comment: a good thing to read on: https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/should-you-reset-your-css/

Comment: @tacoshy why is there horizontal scroll in snippet when using `width: 100vw;` as view port width is accurate width of complete screen what is the reason behind the scrolls

Comment: because it takes the viewport width and applies it to the `.front-page`-element. As soon as a y-scrollbar from the body pops in (which consumes space) then you see that the overflow appears. If you hide the scrollbar with `* { scrollbar-width: 0; }` then no horizontal overflow will appear. One of the reasons why you should not apply `width: 100vw;` or very carefully and only in very specific situations. Maintain the default `width: auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `position:` property to create the layout of the page is generally considered bad practice.
 If you want to eliminate the default margin use `body { margin: 0}` and omit the `position` property from `.front-page`. Then the elements will be positioned under eachother.